# login control without returnurl

Tags: asp.net, authentication

is it possible to use the login control without returnurl?

```
    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server"  
PasswordRecoveryUrl="PaswRecovery" 
DestinationPageUrl="~/Home" 
EnableViewState="False" 
                OnLoggedIn="Login1_LoggedIn">

    </asp:Login>
```

Here a picture of the url:

[image]

can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's an in-built feature of the .NET framework.  I'm not sure how you work around that, as most likely that's a module within the ASP.NET framework controlling that.  What you should be able to do is ignore it, and handle the redirection in the LoggingIn or LoggedIn event to go wherever you want to...